# Naming an array with a variable in Java

Tags: java, arrays, variables, naming

So I'm trying to create a program to run through and make many arrays for me, but, the code I'm using makes no sense for the compiler:

```
int n = 0;

while (n<500) {
    int[ ] n;
    n = new int[n];
    ...
    Then code to populate the array on it's own
    ...
    n++;
}
```

The issue is when the array is created with a variable. I've tried to convert it to a string and name with that, but no dice.

Comment: Semantic Error: Question doesn't make sense.

Comment: both your variables for the size of the array and the array itself are named `n`, I assume this will cause a compile error.

Comment: you can not define "n" two times like this. It does not make any sense

Answer (score 3):

Here's my guess (though the question is unclear):

- name the array with a different name than the int variable.
- `int` and `while` are lower-case

Something like

```
while(..){ 
   int[] array = new int[n];
   ...
}
```

Answer (score 0):

I think you should work with ArrayList:

http://download.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/api/java/util/ArrayList.html

You can add as many elements as you need. If you need an Object[], you can convert with method toArray().

Sample:

```
 List list = new ArrayList();
 list.add(1);
 Integer[] array = list.toArray();
```